# How does different shuffleboard powder affect the disks' speed

Tags: friction, speed, surface-tension

I do know there is friction and surface tension involved here but am not sure on how exactly does different kinds of shuffleboard powder affect the disks' speed.

So taking into the account the different material composition (More info: https://bargames101.com/shuffleboard-powder/):

- How does the powder affect the disks?
- What are the physical principles and calculations that can be applied to determine how much it speeds up the disks compared to no powder (Or decelerate then less)